# Is it possible to embed a Stream group on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, embedded, office-365-video-portal

I want to embed video's from a Stream group on SharePoint but unfortunately I can only choose "All of Stream", "Channels" and/or "Single Video's". Is there a way to embed a whole Stream group?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge there is no such feature to embed all videos shared in a group. You may post your idea in [UserVoice](https://stream.uservoice.com/forums/133762-general) for further discussion.